# Django NoReverseMatch url

Tags: django, django-urls

I can't figure out why I'm returning the following error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for '' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Here is the link in my template:

```
<li><a href="{% url catalog_home %}  }">Home</a></li>
```

Here are my main urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()


urlpatterns = patterns('',

(r'^', include('merged.catalog.urls')),
(r'^cart/', include('merged.cart.urls')),
(r'^checkout/', include('merged.checkout.urls')),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Here is the sub urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include

urlpatterns = patterns('merged.catalog.views',
(r'^$','index', {'template_name': 'catalog/index.html'}, 'catalog_home'),
)
```

It seems like everything is in order, but maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some changes that might help.

In your template:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'catalog_home' %}  }">Home</a></li>
```

In your urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include

urlpatterns = patterns('merged.catalog.views',
    (r'^$','index', {'template_name': 'catalog/index.html'}, name='catalog_home'),
)
```

Comment: Thank you, this must have been a change in recent versions.